# CodeMagic Shows An Empty List

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, codemagic

For the last few weeks all of my apps have disappeared from CodeMagic[image]

I've tried disconnecting the repositories and reconnecting them by nothing changed. Filtering or searching does not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you added Codemagic from GitHub Marketplace?

Comment: It magically started working again yesterday...

Comment: ok, nice to hear that :)